# How to ensure code is not execute between two times?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a while loop and I need to not execute code beween 5pm est on friday and 5pm est on Sunday.

I get est time using the follow:

```
    import datetime
    from datetime import timedelta
    from pytz import timezone
    est = timezone('US/Eastern')
    now_utc = datetime.datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
    now_est = now_utc.astimezone(est)
    if firday5pm < now_est < suday5pm:
          pass
```

So...how do I get firday5pm  and suday5pm?

Comment: Have you considered writing a `cron` job or does this *have* to be a python task?

Comment: there will be no cron.

Comment: You got the solution. Construct a condition on WeekDay & Hour from datetime objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone
est = datetime.datetime.now(timezone('US/Eastern'))
day, hour = est.weekday(), est.hour
if (day == 5 and hour > 17) or (day == 6) or (day == 7 and hour <17):
    print('Stop work.  It is a weekend!')
```